# How to play rtmp link in avplayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, rtmp

I'm trying to play **rtmp** link in **avplayer**. However it's not playing. What should I do?

```
self.avAsset = AVAsset(URL: NSURL(string: rtmpUrlString)!)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

AVPlayer doesn't support RTMP streaming.

The easiest way to play RTMP stream on iOS devices is play it via `VLCKit`.

1. add `pod 'MobileVLCKit-unstable', '3.0.0a23'` to your podfile.
2. run `pod install` to install it.
3. add `#import <MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.h>` in your bridging header file to make this framework available in Swift
4. in your view controller initiate VLC Media Player and start playing stream:

   ```
   var player: VLCMediaPlayer!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       player = VLCMediaPlayer()
       player.media = VLCMedia(url: URL(string: "rtmp://сс.tv/sea")!)
       player.drawable = view
   }

   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewDidAppear(animated)
       if !player.isPlaying {
           player.play()
       }
   }
   ```